# Making mould pieces for model too big for 3D printer

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I am trying to import an STL model and edit it, so the model's walls are thickened. Afterwards, the model is divided into smaller sections, to allow 3D printing of the pieces.  Each one of the pieces must be generated with flanges and holes, to allow reassembly of the model.

I have tried using geometry nodes to achieve a one click solution, but with little success, and i have tried using Python to run my own custom code, to even less success.
My hope had been to run my own custom code, but such hopes has been dashed.

My question is, am i going about this wrong? Does the answer lie in Blender only land? How would you attack this problem?

Comment: And how these flanges and holes looks like? Can you post some images

Comment: I am afraid i do not have an image to post, due to the nature of the problem. I have to generate the pieces with the flanges on, which i failed to do. The size of the flanges, the number of holes in them and the number of pieces is to be automated.

Comment: Without knowing how the result should look like, it likely won't be possible to answer your question.